# Iphone web view during use of Camera

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to open webview  during use of camera in app.if it is possible  plz let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
- (BOOL)startCameraPickerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)delegateObject  
{  
    //NSLog(@"008 ::Create Postcard :: start photo camera");
    if ((![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) || (delegateObject == nil) || (controller == nil)) {  
        return NO;  
    }  

      UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
      picker.delegate = self; 

    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
//  overlay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
//  overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    {create your webview here}



    [overlay addSubview:webview];
    [webview release];
    [picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

    [controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  
    return YES;  
}
```

If you have enough recources on the phone it might could work i guess